# How to locally store a computed variable property once in data

Tags: vue.js

I have a computed variable getting a value from the VUEX store. I only want to get this value once, and then save it locally into a variable so I can edit the said variable without doing any mutations on my store value. How can this be done?

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: as long as you only edit the value in the component where you have it and not use it as a prop, it should work like a typical variable. Alternatively, you can use a copy method and copy it into a different variable and use that instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using something similar to the other answer:

```
      data() {
        return {
          LocalText: { type: String },
        }
      },
      computed: {
        ...mapGetters('store', ['storevar']),
        currentText: function () {
          return this.storevar
        },
      },
      created() {
        this.LocalText= this.currentText
      }
```

What I have done here is that I first made a new variable for the text to be locally stored - LocalText. I have also added a getter that gets the store variable from the store and a computed function that returns the value of the storevar. Finally, I have assigned the value of the storevar to my LocalText when the page is first created using the created() function.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is create a computed property with a get and set method:

```js
data() {
  return {
    myValueCopy: null
  }
},
computed: {
  myValue: {
    get() {
      if (this.myValueCopy === null) {
        return this.$store.getters.myValue;
      }
      return this.myValueCopy;
    }, 
    set(value) {
      this.myValueCopy = value;
    }
  }
}
```

If there's no local copy of the data return the store value, else return the copy. When setting the data, update the local copy not the store.